# Tabelview Cell won't show correctly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

My tableview cell won't show correctly. I have no idea what the problem is. When I launch the simulator it will show this: [Simulator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq6Uo.png) I have used Contraints and I know for sure that the Contraints are correct. This is how it needs to be: [How it must look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVRe9.png) Please help!

Comment: `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` returns... ?

Comment: Change your `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: ca you add code of which you have implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these in your code

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 80.0
    }
```

If you have multiple heights then put condition like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        return 50
    }else{
      retrn 120
    }
}
```

Or use automatic dimension, with resizes every cell automatically according to its content:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { 
     return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
 }
```